# Is a get given by remote control good?

Tags: divorce, judaism

Can a man give a get over to his wife either directly or out in her rishus via a drone operated by him?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: IIRC the Rambam allows the giving of a get via an elephant or a monkey... but doesnt mention drones ;)

Comment: IIRC from the Mishnah on this topic, perek 2 or 3, he can throw it in the street and if it lands closer to her than to him she's been served and it's kosher. This would seem to be an extension of that